# Telerik vs Infragistics vs DevX? WPF 3rd party controls. (Grid)

Tags: wpf-controls, devexpress, telerik-grid, infragistics

I have used Telerik WPF Rad controls v10, they are good. But didn't used it's RadGrid.

And also I haven't used Infragistics and DevX controls for WPF.

Keeping in mind the easy and detailed documentation and easy to implement controls and support, Kindly suggest me WPF 3rd Party controls in terms of Datagrid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I'd choose DevX. I'm pleased with their support *and* I know their controls because I've used them ( for ASP.NET, WinForms ).

A good choice, nevertheless is to choose one you know. To be fair: All grid components will do great if you're on the standard track. As soon as you'll have something to implement that is not a general purpose usage it will get harder. This is - IMHO - true for all third party controls.

At least DevX has forums installed, maybe take a look there and on the forums of the other two options. Compare based on your needs and what you find online. That's the best suggestion you can get.

And by the way: we're all here in our spare time. We're not paid answering machines. So tell it's urgent, but do not  await a quick reply. That could be seen as really impolite.

Comment: Today, I came to know that Telerik Radcontrols doesn't support WPF 4. And even I can't see for Infragistics. I dont know, are their controls fully supportable to WPF 4.0 ot just few controls. Do suggest?

Comment: I don'T know for Infragistics and Telerik but DevExpress controls are - at least the one's I used - can be used in WPF 4. I'm surprised that Telerik or Infragistics shouldn't support WPF 4 - maybe they deliver separate assemblies just like DevExpress.

Comment: Telerik components for WPF do have support for WPF 4, you just need to go into the extra downloads section under WPF and we have a WPF4 build there.  :)

Comment: For Infragistics, the XamDataGrid is supported in WPF 4.  If you install NetAdvantage for WPF Line Of Business you will get two versions of the assembly installed, one for WPF 3 and one for WPF 4.

Answer (score 3):

I have used them all and the bottom line is this:

- devexpress are outstanding quality and functionality but have a greater learning curve
- Telerik are great; not quite as feature rich as devex but easier to get up and running
- infragistics / component one are in my view "also rans"

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with the XamDataGrid and it requires hours of maintenance after each feature around it to keep all the features like grouping working.  On top of that, it doesn't quite support templates the way that all of the .Net framework controls do.  It is quite painful to template anything.

I would stay away from the Infragistics controls, and I use the DataGrid included in the framework wherever possible since my organization will not buy a license for another grid.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with both Infragistics and DevExpress grid. If you need to get in deep and use lots of functionality offered by one, go with DevExpress. Our application uses server-side binding where you have business objects talking to database using stored procedures. Grid itself has no control over the query parameters. With this type of binding, you have to use lot's of customization and we ended up switching to DevExpress, because Ifragistices just couldn't handle it, there were bugs that our best programmers were not able to overcome. After we started using DevXpress Grid, we ended up replacing all Ifragistics controls with DevX and cancelling the subscription. It took over two month of labor but was totally worth it.

Comment: Are you talking about WPF controls or SL controls?

Answer (score 0):

I am only familiar with the Infragistics controls and would encourage you to evaluate the controls on your own to see which control will best meet your needs.

Infragistics has two WPF grids, the XamDataGrid and the XamGrid.  The blog post here compares the two and may help you decide if you are trying to decide which grid would be better between the two:
http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/engineering/archive/2011/11/11/xamgrid-vs-xamdatagrid-conceptual-and-feature-comparison.aspx